# 240 V AFCI substituting two 120 V not AFCI breakers

Tags: gfci, afci

Could 240 V - 20 A AFCI breaker be used to supply power to two 120 V - 20 A circuits requiring AFCI protection?
Recently wired to two separated 120 V 20 A non AFCI breakers but with common neutral?

Comment: Just to confirm, this is an MWBC, right?

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel?